# Dice combinations to a total

Tags: algorithm, dice, die

Trying to find a nice algorithm for working out d4 dice combinations for a total. For example 3 dice with four sides, all the combinations to make 4 would give: 004 013 112 022

I will be using c# but python or pseudo would be great. Just need some help for the algorithm. Would always be a four sided die but total and number of dice would be parameters.

Any ideas would be great. Thank you.

Comment: So 004 means you actually only throw one of the three dice?

Comment: Yes. So it’s a maximum number of dice. Most ways I think of use for loops.  One for each die but this is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tweak to trincot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68564042/6438819) that doesn't require the creation of intermediate lists, and which computes a minimum value for the current dice, resulting in less wasted calls ([.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MoVnO8)).

```
public static ArrayList combos(int nDice, int tot, int max)
{
    var res = new ArrayList();
    combos(res, "", nDice, tot, max);
    return res;
}

private static void combos(ArrayList res, String sol, int nDice, int tot, int max)
{
    if(tot == 0)
    {
        res.Add(sol);
        return;
    }
    
    for(int side = 1+(tot-1)/nDice; side <= Math.Min(tot, max); side++)
        combos(res, sol+side, nDice-1, tot-side, side);
}
```

Test:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) {
    int nDice = 3;
    int nFaces = 4;
    for(int tot=1; tot<=nDice*nFaces+1; tot++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("\nTot: " + tot);
        foreach (var combo in combos(nDice, tot, nFaces)) {
            Console.WriteLine (combo);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
tot: 1
1

tot: 2
11
2

tot: 3
111
21
3

tot: 4
211
22
31
4

tot: 5
221
311
32
41

tot: 6
222
321
33
411
42

tot: 7
322
331
421
43

tot: 8
332
422
431
44

tot: 9
333
432
441

tot: 10
433
442

tot: 11
443

tot: 12
444

tot: 13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion.

For instance, in Python it would look like this:

```py
def combis(num_dice, target, minval=1):
    if target == 0:
        return [""]  # solution
    if num_dice < 1 or target < 0:
        return [] # no solution

    res = []
    for side in range(minval, min(5, target + 1)):
        for combi in combis(num_dice - 1, target - side, side):
            res.append(str(side) + combi)
    return res
    
print(combis(3, 4))
```

If really this had to be done in Python, then one would use a library like `itertools`.

The output is a list of strings, where each character in a string is a digit representing the side of a die. The strings are never longer than the first argument (`num_dice`), but they can be shorter, meaning fewer dice are involved. You could pad those with "0" if desired.

### Implementation in C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;

class MainClass {
    public static ArrayList combis(int numDice, int target, int minval=1) {
        var res = new ArrayList();
        if (target == 0) {
            res.Add(""); // solution
        } else if (numDice > 0 && target > 0) {
            for (int side = minval; side < 5 && side <= target; side++) {
                foreach (var combi in combis(numDice - 1, target - side, side)) {
                    res.Add(side.ToString() + combi);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        // Example run
        foreach (var combi in combis(3, 4)) {
            Console.WriteLine (combi);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you, was thinking i might have to go down the recursive route.

Comment: Have problems with the C# with the embedded for loop....

Comment: I added a C# implementation to my answer. I'm not fluent in C#, so it could probably be improved.